# Creating a sitemap class returning URL with two arguments

Tags: django, sitemap

I have a set of items = [a,b,c]

And I have a page that takes in two items and compare them.

So the URLs look like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/compare/a/b

http://127.0.0.1:8000/compare/a/c

http://127.0.0.1:8000/compare/b/c

How could I make a sitemap class to represent all of them?

*This is my sitemap class with one argument

```
class ItemsSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "monthly"
    priority = 0.8

    def items(self):
        return Items.objects.order_by('id')

    def location(self, obj):
        return '/items/%s' % (obj.id)
```

Comment: Is `/compare/b/a` also a valid URL?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes Willem, /compare/b/a is also valid, but I would like to exclude /compare/a/a if possible

Comment: Use [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to generate all possible pairs - `list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3], 2))` -> `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]`

Comment: @IainShelvington Hi Iain, in which part of the class do I do that? and how can I integrate that in the location method?

Comment: @stedy probably in `items`, then in `location` the two parts are `obj[0]` and `obj[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is how I got it to work:

```
from itertools import combinations    

class ComparisonSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "monthly"
    priority = 0.8

    def items(self):
        itemlist= Items.objects.order_by('id')
        itemids= itemlist.values_list('id',flat=True)
        pairs = list(combinations(itemids,2))
        return pairs

    def location(self,pairs):
        return '/comparison/{}/{}'.format(pairs[0],pairs[1])
```

Thank you Iain for the tip!